# No suitable drivers found

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am new in Netbeans. I am working on a project on java using Netbeans IDE and mysql sever in Ubuntu. My database is successfully build . I have created the JFrame of a login page which is connected to the database. Page is running successfully,

But when I am giving the input, and clicking the button(ex,. Submit), its giving the following error

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ganDb[on APP]
```

And a pop up is coming saying:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING at us.  :-/

Comment: This caps-locked font scares me, please change it.

Comment: As an aside.  Did you actually *read* the helpful tag pop-ups?  What does this have to do with the [tag:netbeans-platform]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is not in your project classpath, you can right-click in the project an then in "properties" next in "libraries" and click in add library and find .jar file that contain de driver and add them to your project.

If you are using jpa you can see in "services"->"databases" that your driver is in it and the connection have been initialized.